# react-native webview control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

Is there a way to prevent webview from switching in the event handler method for a specific URL request in WebView's onNavigationStateChange method? Except for the stopLoading method. What I want is to run a different browser using Linking for a specific URL and keep the previous state for the current WebView.